# How to integrate a normal distribution

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

I want to prove that the following quadrature formula:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(x)N(x|m, \sigma^2) dx \approx \frac{2}{3}g(m) +\frac{1}{6}g(m+\sigma\sqrt{3})+\frac{1}{6}g(m-\sigma\sqrt{3})$$
holds when g is polynomial less or equal to 5.

I managed to prove it for degree 0 with $g(x) = x^0 = 1$. We know that the integral of the normal gives 1.

However I am a bit lost starting from degree 1 where it is obviously easy to compute the RHS of the equality but I don't know how to deal with a product involving a normal. Using a software didn't help.

Comment: What, exactly, is meant by $\approx$ in this context.  And do you mean a polynomial of *degree* $\leq 5$?

Comment: Here, the polynomial means the degree means $x^0$ up to $x^5$.

Comment: [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss–Hermite_quadrature).

Comment: @CountIblis Thanks a lot. This solves my issue. Plus I found a table of the different weights.

Comment: The formula used weights of 3-point Gauss-Hermite formula. Since the above formula is exact up to polynomial of degree $2p-1$, this means that it is exact for a degree of g less or equal to 5.